# Cannot type "ć" on Hungarian layout

Tags: keyboard-layout, internationalization, system-settings

I need help with keyboard layouts. My layout is Hungarian and on Windows I could type `ć` using AltGr-9 + c which is a `c` with an acute. However AltGr-9 + Space gives me a single quote (`'`) and <kbd>AltGr</kbd>-<kbd>9</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> gives me this `ç` a `c` with a cedilla despite there is an acute printed on key 9. I tried the Hungarian and Hungarian (Standard) layouts in system settings as well, but the others I cannot understand (dead keys/comma/dot... what do these mean?). I didn't notice any problems with any other characters. Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: There are many hungarian keyboards already installed in Ubuntu. Try checking the other layouts?

Comment: It should be bug with the dead key. I just tested **English international** and saw the same problem with _dead acute_ and "c" which behaves like _dead cedilla_.

Comment: This bugreport seems related: https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/1079234

Comment: Could you please tell me where can I find info on the meaning of the kb layout names? I ofc know what's 101 or qwertz/qwerty, but what's keys/comma/dead keys? I can ofc try changing layouts randomly, but it would be nice to know.

Comment: _Comma_ or _dot_ stands for the decimal point on numpad; and _dead keys_ or _eliminate dead keys_ is obviously referred to include dead keys in the layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Plain text programs**

In plain text programs such as Gedit or gnome-terminal, do the following:

*Right click your open document or the terminal window* >> choose *Input Methods* from the context menu >> and then choose *Simple* (instead of the default *System (IBus (Intelligent Input Bus))*

<kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>9</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> will now work as intended.

**LibreOffice**

In LibreOffice, the AltGr/Compose key sequences work as intended, but you need to add <kbd>Shift</kbd> to get to the 3rd level:

<kbd>AltGr</kbd> (or Compose) + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>9</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but pressing AltGr + Shift + 9 immediately gives me the acute character, so I have no chance pressing `c` afterwards.

Comment: I tried it in LibreOffice Writer and it worked fine, which is why I specified that in the answer. I just tried it in Gedit and it's also going straight to acute. I'm not sure yet how these two editors handle it differently. Which editor are you using and will LO Writer work for you? In gedit, I can inset the correct char  with ctrl-shift-u+107

Comment: The bug appears to be in Ibus. The plain text apps, such as gedit and gnome-terminal (these are the only ones I have tested) are running the key presses through Ibus _even when Ibus appears to be off_. Turning off Ibus for real solves the problem. LibreOffice is working correctly with according to AltGr/Compose key sequences. I'm not sure if it's possible to use AltGr+9+c with LO but I'm guessing not.

Comment: Changing the input method did the trick! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative for inserting this character is to insert its **unicode**.

To insert a unicode there are two ways:

**1st**

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>, an underlined *u* appears;
- insert the unicode and press <kbd>space</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

**2nd**

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> and keep holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>, the underlined *u* appears;
- insert the unicode and release the keys.

Using *Character Map* you can find the unicode **u+107** for the small letter **ć**, and **u+106** for the capital **Ć**.