# Stabilizing characters like `< >`, `{ }` and `[ ]`

Tags: keyboard-layout, input-language, rtl

When the language layout is changed to a right to left language; in some standard editing places (e.g. the address bar of Google Chrome), characters like `<`, `{` and `[` automatically become `>`, `}` and `]` just by changing language layout.

Is there a way to prevent this and make these characters stable?

Comment: Could you add a showcase with screenshot.

Comment: @Sneetsher: needs a film. add arabic to the languages in Chromium address bar type the charater < alone. Then change layout to English.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I didn't get what you mean for the first time, because I got familiar with that. I think it will be OK, if you can expect results.

That behavior is a standard from [Unicode Bidirectional Algorithm](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr9/#P2). So the dominant BiDi direction is taken from first strong character in the paragraph.

- So what I think it happens in this case:

  1. First direction with empty textbox is taken from locale/language configuration. As you said Arabic is an RTL language. So cursor on the right.

     [image: initial empty textbox, RTL direction]
  2. Input `<` but it showed as `>`. It is a neutral char so no affects on direction. Why it is flipped? Short answer: Unicode standard, :) accept that anyway. Well its name is [Less-than sign](http://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=%3C), So ... In RTL/Arabic, formula's start from right side, it should be flipped. What do you think...no?!!!

     [image: textbox with bidi neutral character]
  3. Input a Latin char `g`. It's a strong **L** (left) char, so this paragraph is detected as LTR.

     [image: textbox with strong left character]
  4. Backspace to delete `g`. But notice where the cursor.

     [image: textbox with bidi neutral character after removing a strong left character]

  Now, example `[`, it was wrongly named [Left square bracket](http://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=%5B). It should be some thing like *Open square bracket* (It is BiDi neutral and flipped in RTL)

All developers try to follow standards. So noway they will force textbox to be RTL or LTR, Auto is the best for most users.

- So for you, the best thing I can offer is to use Unicode BiDi Control Char's.

  ```
  U+200F right-to-left mark (RLM)
  ```

  1. In empty address bar, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>, small underlined `u` shows up, enter `200f` then <kbd>Enter</kbd>

     [image: GTK/Gnome Unicode input]
  2. See `<` did not flip as LTR.

     [image: GTK/Gnome force RTL direction]

  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> is GTK/Gnome specific. KDE misses for such option and it seems not to be fixed, as this bug report mention the conflict between KDE/Qt/Xorg [Need way to insert arbitrary Unicode characters in Kubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/531208).
- As it is just a matter of few characters, you could remap non needed keys or map non used ones. For example, I'm using *US English (international AltGr dead keys)*

  1. Open its `xkb` layout file for editing:

     ```
     sudo nano /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us
     ```
  2. Look for the group definition that with same name:

     ```
     xkb_symbols "altgr-intl" {

         name[Group1]= "English (international AltGr dead keys)";
     ```
  3. Let's look as example for `r` (easy to remember),: <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> → RLM, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> → LRM. Instead of `ë` & `Ë`. Replace:

     ```
     key <AD04> { [        r, R,           ediaeresis,   Ediaeresis      ] };
     ```

     With:

     ```
     key <AD04> { [        r, R,           U200F,        U200E           ] };
     ```
  4. Update xkb

     ```
     sudo dpkg-reconfigure xkb-data
     ```
  5. Switch to another layout then back, it will be active immediately.

  **Notes:**

  - Use same method to add them to Arabic layout, if you want to be able to use it from both layouts.
  - You may use `U+061C ؜ ‭arabic letter mark (ALM)` instead of RLM as you are an Arabic user.
  - `xkb` supports other Unicode code entry format, `0x100200f` eq. `U200F` (ie `0x100` as prefix)
  - To avoid overwriting of the modified key map by `xkb-data` updates, the best is to create a new custom XKB map. See [How to add a new keyboard layout (Custom keyboard layout definition)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/482678/how-to-add-a-new-keyboard-layout-custom-keyboard-layout-definition/) or [What are the steps needed to create new keyboard layout on ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510024/what-are-the-steps-needed-to-create-new-keyboard-layout-on-ubuntu?lq=1)
  - It's possible add all other Unicode control characters. Some application has already an option in Popup Menu of the Multi-line Input Text Box. Example Poedit:

    [image: poedit, bidi control characters menu]

**Nice to read for further understanding:**

- [Wikipedia: Bi-directional text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bi-directional_text)
- [Understanding Bidirectional (BIDI) Text in Unicode](http://www.iamcal.com/understanding-bidirectional-text/)

**References:**

- [Unicode Bidirectional Algorithm](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr9/#P2)
- How to enter any Unicode not available on keyboard, see [Cannot type “ć” on Hungarian layout](https://askubuntu.com/questions/257824/cannot-type-c-on-hungarian-layout)
- [Howto: Custom keyboard layout definitions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Howto:%20Custom%20keyboard%20layout%20definitions)
- [Wikipedia: Unicode input](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_input)
- [Reconfigure keyboard layout - 13.10, 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/436686/reconfigure-keyboard-layout-13-10-14-04)
- [Wikibooks: FOSS Localization/Annex B: Technical Aspects](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/FOSS_Localization/Annex_B:_Technical_Aspects) (Ref. for `0x100` prefix)

Comment: thanks. for me ctrl+shift + u does not work in KDE. probably it's unity or gnome specific. It'd fantastic if some characters, e.g. ',[]{}' can opt out from direction specific treatments (and always are regraded as ltr), so that they are more compatible with keyboard symbols and less confusing.

Comment: You are right, It seems not to be fixed in KDE, as this bug report mention the conflict between KDE/Qt/Xorg [Need way to insert arbitrary unicode characters in Kubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/531208). I will search if there is any workaround.

Comment: @MinimusHeximus, I updated my answer with Unicode input workaround using xkb. I have only Gnome/Unity. Please, let me know if it doesn't work in KDE.

Comment: Seems I have to use something like `0x100200F` instead, I don't know if it is the same as `U200F`.

Comment: I'm not sure, I couldn't get it defined in `more /usr/include/X11/keysymdef.h | grep -i 200F`

Comment: @MinimusHeximus, yes, it is the same "*(In fact, this may be a more effective way for adding new keysyms.) The Unicode value must be prefixed with "0x100" to describe the keysym for a single character.*" , Ref: [Wikibooks: FOSS Localization/Annex B: Technical Aspects](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/FOSS_Localization/Annex_B:_Technical_Aspects). Thank you I learned new things from you.

Comment: thank you for reviving this unanswered question and useful infomation.