# Wrong cursor directions and brackets in right to left languages

Tags: rtl

I successfully write in Arabic.

But there's a problem with symbols like brackets (), <> , and full stops. They are displayed in wrong directions in case of brackets and in wrong place in case of full stop (at the beginning of the line instead the end)

And the another wired problem: when you press the right arrow the cursor moves to left , and when u press left ,cursor moves right.

Sorry , with all my respect to Ubuntu programmers, How you cannot solve this silly problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- About `[]<>{}`..etc, I think you mean same case as [Stabilizing characters like <>, {} and []](https://askubuntu.com/questions/380776/stabilizing-characters-like-and/438709#438709)
- Concerning cursor direction, There are two modes:

  1. Logical: Cursor moves as the text is stored in memory.
  2. Visual: Cursor moves as the text is displayed.

  Most user expect to see Visual cursor movement (Like in MS Windows). But not all application have it or use it by default.

  With Logical Cursor Movement, the cursor move as visual in LTR languages but it look like reversed in RTL languages. You should think: Left as Backward and Right as Forward.

  Logical cursor movement was counted by RTL languages users as bug, before implementing visual movement algorithm. Nowadays, GTK/Qt/KDE covers such missing option in applications as Unicode become universal standard. So most applications developed using these kits use visual cursor movement.

  - Gedit uses visual cursor.
  - As I know, LibreOffice (which I think you was aiming to) supports both with Logical as default. To change it:

    Tools → Options → Language Settings → Complex Text Layout  → Cursor Control: Movement.

[image]

Recommended Readings:

- [Cursor motion & bi-directional text](http://marijnhaverbeke.nl/blog/cursor-in-bidi-text.html)

Answer (score 0):

Arabic letters are written from right to left so that the brackets,fullstops are displayed in the wrong direction.