# Reconfigure keyboard layout - 13.10, 14.04

Tags: keyboard-layout

I always modify keyboard layouts to add special characters as my needs. To modify the layout I open the codes under:

`/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/`

The changes would apply after a re-login, or a reboot for the default one.

**But now** on Ubuntu 13.10 and 14.04, with the new text entry settings, the changes don’t take effect even after a reboot, **if I’ve enabled them before editting**.

Is there any way to force Ubuntu to reconfigure keyboard layouts, Somewhat like `dpkg-reconfigure locales` for locales? The files are saved correctly!

Comment: Yeah, it’s duplicate! :|

Comment: :) It seems to me that your solution is the canonical one. Also I have tested it. the command clean up  `/var/lib/xkb/` folder. So same effects. You may add this solution to the other question.

Comment: When people ask why Linux isn't ready for the desktop yet, show them this issue. No mere mortal could have been expected to figure this out.

Comment: @EdwardFalk, yeah, and now it's found new dimensions. Every time I log in my user account the keyboard layout acts like the one I chose during installation (for me, en_US). I need to switch layout once to work properly! I believe in open-source, but it's gonna be disappointing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

:D It’s simply:

`dpkg-reconfigure xkb-data`