# How to enter Arabic superscript and subcript alef in keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, input-method, arabic

How to insert Arabic character for superscript Alef (like in **هٰ**) and subscript Alef (like in **هٖ**) from keyboard directly? Are they commonly used in Arabic or only used in *Mushaf Uthmani* of The Holy Quran?

*Actually the subscript Alef is not rendered below **ه** in my computer (Ubuntu Raring), but on the left side of the letter instead. However the superscipt alef is rendered above the letter. <strike>I doubt I copied a wrong character :)</strike> Update: I've checked that it was a not a wrong character, because another machine renders the subscript Alef right below the character, so it was rendering problem in Raring.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use *Character Map* find their Unicode code. like `U+0656 ARABIC SUBSCRIPT ALEF`
- Then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> (a small under-lined `u` shows up), type Unicode code `656`

See for other input-method options [Cannot type “ć” on Hungarian layout](https://askubuntu.com/questions/257824/cannot-type-c-on-hungarian-layout)

For faster input, you may modify your current keyboard layout or create a customized one. See these answers:

- [Stabilizing characters like `< >`, `{ }` and `\[ \]`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/380776/stabilizing-characters-like-and/)
- [How to add a new keyboard layout (Custom keyboard layout definition)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/482678/how-to-add-a-new-keyboard-layout-custom-keyboard-layout-definition/)

Comment: If only there's a faster way rather than 7-keyboard-stroke :D

Comment: @BornToCode, yep there is. updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know:

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> = **هَ**

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> = **هِ**

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> = **هً**

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> = **هٍ**

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> = **هُ**

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> = **هّ**

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option I currently use. Instead of using that default keyboard layout which does not include superscript and subscript Alef, just use another keyboard layout.

Create a custom layout or get it from [this custom Arabic keyboard layout](https://gist.github.com/fikr4n/7aefc8f0358339680bcc). Place the layout file in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/` directory and register it by modifying `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml` file, add it in `<layoutList>` node like this (taken from the link above):

```
<layoutList>
  ...
  <layout>
    <configItem>
      <name>SIMPLE FILE NAME, NOT FULL PATH</name>
      <shortDescription>USUALLY TWO-LETTER COUNTRY CODE</shortDescription>
      <description>USUALLY FULL COUNTRY NAME</description>
      <languageList>
        <iso639Id>THREE-LETTER LANGUAGE CODE</iso639Id>
      </languageList>
    </configItem>
    <variantList></variantList>
  </layout>
...
</layoutList>
```

Now just press <kbd>`</kbd> (backtick/tilde key) for `U+0670 ARABIC LETTER SUPERSCRIPT ALEF` and <kbd>Shift+R</kbd> for `U+0656 ARABIC SUBSCRIPT ALEF`. There is also `U+0657 ARABIC INVERTED DAMMA` by pressing <kbd>Shift+4</kbd>.

Answer (score -1):

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> = هً

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> = هٍ

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> = هٌ

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> = هّ

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> 
 then <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> = هُّ

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> = هْ

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> = ~

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> 
 then <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> = هِّ

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> = هُ

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> = هَ

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> = هِ

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> 
 then <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> = هَّ

Comment: You better delete this answer before someone vote it down. Please read the question carefully.